# How can we get SE to stop migrating questions which clearly need work here

Tags: discussion, migration

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13188/2322

This is going to be closed (hopefully) since it's a vague complete mess. It's not even remotely appropriate for Stack Exchange in its current form.

After being closed, it will then get locked and eventually auto-delete, in spite of having what might be a good core question there.

Does someone here have to approve migration from The Workplace? I do not understand why questions such as the above are transferred here.

Comment: related MSO feature request: [Suggested migrations review at target site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151345/165773): *"For more control over incompetent migrations... try a new kind review... Located at target site, it would contain a list of questions flagged / voted for migration. Target site users... could submit their feedback on whether the proposed question is a good fit for migration..."*

Comment: Does this happen frequently? // If not, I wouldn't lose any sleep over it. The question you referenced seems like an outlier.

Comment: Here are the links to [all posts migrated here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/here) and [stats on the last 90 days](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats).  While eventual deleted or downvoted questions exist in that list, it doesn't seem overwhelming to me, and the community appears to be taking appropriate actions (downvotes and closes/rejections or upvotes and edits and answers) where warranted.  Used to be mods talked about it among themselves, but I believe SE wants the tools to be used and the community to handle it, which it seems we do.

Comment: After watching migrations for a month or so after my comment above, I do think that the mods might want to have a little chat in Teachers Lounge with the Productivity mods, just to make sure everyone is on the same page re: scope of topics and types of questions.